# For what values of $m$ is there a common root to $mx^2+2x+1=0$ and $x^2+2x+m=0$?

Tags: roots, quadratics

> If the equation $mx^2+2x+1 = 0$ and $x^2+2x+m = 0$ have a common root, find the possible values of $m$ and the value of the common root in each case.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: Hint: eliminate $x^2$, then solve for $x$, and substitute into one of the original equations.

Comment: You can use the quadratic fomula find possible roots and set them equal to each other.  That may add for many extraneous solutions though.  Robert Israels suggestion is good and maybe more efficient.

Comment: I am still not sure how to do this. I tried eliminating x^2. I am pretty sure you need to use sum and product of roots combined with the fact that 1 of those roots are common, but i do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a$ be the common root, then $ma^2 - a^2 + 1 - m=0\implies (m-1)(a^2-1) = 0$. Thus if $m \neq 1$, then $a = 1$, and this means $m = -3$. If $m = 1\implies a = -1$ . Thus we have $m = -3, 1$ and the common roots are $1,-1$ respectively.

Answer (score 0):

$mx^2 + 2x + 1 = 0$ will have 2 roots  $\frac {-2 \pm \sqrt{4 - 4m}}{2m}$.

(We must consider that $m = 0$.  If $m = 0$ then $2x+1 = 0$ has root $-\frac 12$ and $x^2 +2x +m = 0$ has roots $x = 0$ and $x = -2$.  So if $m =0$ there are no common roots.  So we may assume $m \ne 0$.

$x^2 + 2x + m= 0$ will have 2 roots $\frac {-2 \pm \sqrt{4-4m}}{2}$.

So there are four cases that this will have a common root:

1) $\frac {-2 + \sqrt{4 - 4m}}{2m}=\frac {-2 + \sqrt{4-4m}}{2}$

$2m = 2$ and $m = 1$.

And $x^2 + 2x + 1=0$ and $x^2 + 2x + 1=0$ are the same equation with the same roots.

2)  $\frac {-2 + \sqrt{4 - 4m}}{2m} = \frac {-2 - \sqrt{4-4m}}{2}$

$\frac{1 -\sqrt{1-m}}m = 1 + \sqrt{1-m}$

$1 -\sqrt{1-m} = m + m\sqrt{1-m}$

$1-m = \sqrt{1-m}(m + 1)$

$\frac {1-m}{m+1} = \sqrt {1 -m}$

$\frac {1-2m + m^2}{1 + 2m + m^2} = 1 -m$

$1 - \frac {4m}{1+2m + m^2} = 1-m$

$4 = 1 + 2m + m^2$

$m^2 + 2m -3 = 0$

$(m+3)(m - 1) = 0$

So $m = -3$ and $m =1$ are solutions.

If $m = -3$ then $-3x^2 + 2x +1 =0$ has a root $x = \frac {-2-\sqrt{4+4*3}}{-6} = 1$ and $x^2 + 2x -3=0$ has a root $x = 1$.

3) $\frac {-2 - \sqrt{4 - 4m}}{2m} = \frac {-2 + \sqrt{4-4m}}{2}$

$\frac {1+\sqrt{1-m}}{m} = 1-\sqrt{1-m}$

$1 + \sqrt{1-m} = m - m\sqrt{1-m}$

$\sqrt{1-m}(1+m) = m -1$

Which is the same as 2) above.

4)$\frac {-2 - \sqrt{4 - 4m}}{2m} = \frac {-2 - \sqrt{4-4m}}{2}$

Whih means $m = 1$ (the same as 1) above.

So $m = 1,-3$ are the two possible values of $m$.

Answer (score 0):

For reference:

> If the equation $mx^2+2x+1=0$ and $x^2+2x+m=0$ have a common root, find the possible values of $m$ and the value of the common root in each case.

Let $a$ be the root.
Multiply the second by $m^2$ and subtract the first:
$$2ma+m^2-2a-1=0 \Rightarrow (m-1)(m+1+2a)=0 \Rightarrow \\
\color{red}{m_1=1} \Rightarrow \color{red}{a_1=-1};\\
m+1+2a=0 \Rightarrow m=-1-2a.$$
Plug this into the first equation:
$$(-1-2a)a^2+2a+1=0 \Rightarrow (2a+1)(1-a^2)=0 \Rightarrow \\
\color{red}{a_2=-\frac12} \Rightarrow \color{red}{m_2\in \emptyset};\\
a_3=-1 \Rightarrow m_3=1;\\
\color{red}{a_4=1} \Rightarrow \color{red}{m_4=-3}.$$
Hence, the possible answers are: $(m,a)=(1,-1), (-3,1)$.